# Understanding Constants in Equations

Tags: abstract-algebra

Consider the equation

y = 2x

The solution set is

{..., (0,0), (1,2), (2,4), (3,6), ...}

Now consider the equation with arbitrary constant c

y = cx

What would this equations solution set be?

Would it depend on the value of c and be the following?

{..., (0,0), (1,c), (2,2c), (3,3c), ...}

Or would we treat it like a variable and give it a solution set like the one below?

{..., (0,0,0), (0,0,1), (0,0,2), ..., (1, 0, 0), (2,0,0), ..., (1,1,1), (2, 1, 1/2), ...}

Comment: It's the former

Answer (score 1):

The first solution set is correct.

Answer (score 1):

If $c$ is a constant, as you already noticed the solution set depends on $c$ and has the form

$$\{(x, cx)\},$$

since you get a new equation for every new $c$.

If $c$ is a variable, you get a solution set as you described at the end.